# redirect https to http URL REWRITE

Tags: ssl, iis, https, http, rewrite

I see alot of help with IIS redirecting IIS from HTTP to HTTPS but I temporally need to redirect HTTPS Traffic to HTTP to solve another problem.

I was going to follow this tutorial and try and switch things around but I have had no luck.

https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9953/38/iis-redirect-http-to-https

Comment: Are you testing with a browser? Modern browsers are pretty smart, and if they have previously accessed a site over HTTPS, they can remember to do this in the future. If your web server also sets an HSTS header, then you are telling your browser to remember to only access this resources over HTTPS.

Comment: Yes so how do I get around that?

Comment: @MicahArmantrout: once HSTS is set (which is still unknown to us) there is now way to get around it apart from clearing the cache in all browsers. The feature is explicitly designed so that no way around it is possible because attackers would specifically try to exploit such a way around.

Comment: @MicahArmantrout depending what problem you need to solve, you can use curl or wget from a command line and access the website like that - by default, you won't encounter caching, security measures, or any other browser features designed to make your application safer...but you need to provide more details as to what your use case is I think to be able to get a useful answer

Answer (score -2):

To peform htaccess redirect to HTTPS, you need to Install SSL certificate. After successful installation of SSL, the first step involves editing of .htaccess file. You can do it via FTP or cPanel File Manager. The second step involves htaccess redirect to https in Apache or NGINX.

Insert this code to the .htaccess file and force all web traffic to use HTTPS.

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT}80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R,L]

For more details visit: https://serverguy.com/security/redirect-http-to-https/

Comment: The question is regarding IIS, not apache or nginx.

Comment: Apart from that, link only answers are not really welcome here. [It would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.